# How to change Android ActionBar color in Xamarin App.Shell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell, .net-standard-2.1

I'm developing an app using Xamarin with .netstandard 2.1 and can't find a way to change the action bar of the android app.

[image]

The blue bar isn't the color I want, and following all the docs and tutorials over internet, I found even a way to change the status bar (where the clock and battery and notifications are), but can't change this blue to Orange.

Can someone tell me what should I'm doing wrong, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the attached property `BackgroundColor="Red"` either globally at `<Shell>` level:

```
<Shell
       ...
       BackgroundColor="Red">
```

Or at `ContentPage` level using:

```
<ContentPage
       ...
       Shell.BackgroundColor="Red">
```

note that this will affect navigation bar (the one you described) and also upper tabs (TabBar).

Answer (score 0):

Inside your shell app xaml file, at the top use Shell.BackgroundColor="Red".

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1.Views"
       Title="App1"
       x:Class="App1.AppShell"
       Shell.BackgroundColor="Red"
       >
```